# Web applications - doGet() - Anonymous Users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new with Google-apps-script and I would appreciate your help with this issue:

I have a function "Brownformat()" that I call from a sidebar that executes the code below:

Code.gs

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('Custom Menu')
  .addItem('Custom Sidebar', 'showSidebar')
  .addToUi();
  showSidebar()
}

function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page')
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
  .setTitle('Sidebar')
  .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  .showSidebar(html);
}

function Brownformat() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().setBackground("#e1b99c");
}
```

Page.html

```
<p>Brown Group</p>
<input type="button" value="" style="background-color:#e1b99c; color:#f00;"
  onclick="google.script.run.Brownformat()" />
```

Basically this function changes the background color of the current cell to brown by clicking a Button on the sidebar.

This function runs perfectly when you are signed in, but it does not run for an anonymous users.

I read that you need to publish your code as web application in order to get around this issue, and to use special call back functions.

Can anyone please show me how to implement this call back function for the piece of code shown above?

Thank you.

Chalo

Comment: clarify, because you cant even show the sidebar (or add menus or click handlers in images etc) for an anonymous user. thats your issue and not the function per se not working, correct?

Comment: Zig, that is correct, but I was under the impression that in order to make a Web app the functions needs to be defined using call back functions. Not only the Brownformat function but like you said also the functions to show the sidebar and custom menus. Thank you.

Comment: yes and from simple triggers like onOpen

Comment: Zig, I edited my original post to include the triggers. Basically I want this code able to run for anonymous users as well. rigth now only works for registered users. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

as it is is impossible to show the sidebar for anonymous users. you would need to make a webapp and include the webapp url in the sheet so they run it manually on another tab.

Comment: I followed this steps: [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) and I get this error: Script function not found: doGet.

Comment: that is unrelated to the code posted in your question. the page you linked clearly says you need a "doGet". make a separate question if still having issues, include the relevant new code there.